# Adding 3 to beginning of random number

Tags: java

```
public static void setIdentificationNumber2(Staff a) {
    if ("Librarian".equals(a.getPosition())) {
        a.setIdentificationNumber(4 + (int) (Math.random() * 999999 + 1));
    } else {
        a.setIdentificationNumber(3 + (int) (Math.random() * 999999 + 1));
    }
}
```

Was just wondering if there was a way to add a 3 to the beginning of any random number generated from this method in the format 3XXXXXX. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you want an id of format `3XXXX`?

Comment: Yes sorry 3XXXXXX

Comment: isn't there a slight chance of getting same number twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a string from your random number, add `"3"` to the front, and then parse it back to an `int`:

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 999999 + 1);
int identificationNumber = Integer.parseInt("3" + Integer.toString(randomNumber));
a.setIdentificationNumber(identificationNumber);
```

And if your number must always be 7 digits long, then you can just add `3000000` to it:

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 999999 + 1);
int identificationNumber = 3_000_000 + randomNumber;
a.setIdentificationNumber(identificationNumber);
```

Comment: to avoid casting, it's worth to use `Random#nextInt()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 999999 + 1);
int identificationNumber = Integer.parseInt("3" + randomNumber);
a.setIdentificationNumber(identificationNumber);
```